# overlap dropdown menu and slideshow

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

I use Zeropoint theme and the drop-down menu in this theme.
When I hover the mouse over a menu, and the menu is expanded, my submenu is placed under the slideshow and is not show completely.

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve it?

Comment: The slideshow you're talking about, is it flash or javascript based? Do you have a url where we can see it ourselves?

Comment: http://devel.codeproject.ir/amad-bsco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem using things like Views Slideshow and NiceMenus.  You can perhaps fix it by changing the CSS of the menu to include the following: `z-index: 99`. If you post a link to the site I can give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: my slide show is Views Slideshow too.
http://devel.codeproject.ir/amad-bsco